# Transform Function Component -> Class Component

Tags: reactjs, components, constants

How to transform this **function complement** to **class component**
:

```
const SyncValidationForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form className ="formmailforbook" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>

      <Field name="email" type="email" component={renderField} label="Email"/>
      <div>
        <button className ="hero_button margin_left" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy translation, you can do the same prop destructuring in the `render` method. Only slight change is that now it's pulling from `this.props`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SyncValidationForm extends Component {
  render () {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className ="formmailforbook" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>

        <Field name="email" type="email" component={renderField} label="Email"/>
        <div>
          <button className ="hero_button margin_left" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: When i using it solution, app rendering, but errors appearing:

invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much easy.. copy the code to the new file and add `export default`before const something like this.

```
export default const SyncValidationForm
```

Import the file as you import other components where ever you want the component and use the imported name as jsx name as usal and provide props.